# Teste FizzBuzz em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer o teste "FIZZBUZZ" que consiste no seguinte:

> Escreva um programa que imprima os números de 1 a 100. Mas para
> múltiplos de três imprima "Fizz" em vez do número e para os múltiplos
> de cinco imprima "Buzz". Para números que são múltiplos de três e
> cinco, imprima "FizzBuzz"

Escrevi o seguinte código, mas ele não está funcionado! Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

```
var n = 1;

while (n <= 100) {
    if ((n % 3) == 0 || (n % 5) == 0) {
        if ((n % 3) == 0 && (n % 5) == 0) {
            console.log("FizzBuzz");
        }
        else if (n % 3 == 0 && (n % 5) !== 0) {
            console.log("Fizz");
        }
        else if ((n % 5) == 0 && (n % 3) !== 0) {
            console.log("Buzz");
        }
    else {
        console.log(n);
    }
    }
n = n + 1;
}
```

Se tiverem sugestões de como deixar meu código mais claro, será muito bem vindo!

Comment: QUal parte não funciona?

Comment: Quando rodo o código e vejo no console do Chrome os números não aparecem!

Comment: Só aparece fizz, buzz ou fizzbuzz você não imprimindo os números.

Comment: **Texto original:** Write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of the number and for the multiples of five print "Buzz". For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print "FizzBuzz"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os números que não são multiplos de 3 ou de 5 não são impressoes porque estão dentro do primeiro if e não existe nenhum console.log para eles.

```
if ((n % 3) == 0 || (n % 5) == 0) {

    } else {
       console.log(n);
    } <-- os demais números depois dessa linha, que não tem nenhum console.log
    n = n + 1;
}
```

Sugestão:

```
var n = 1;

while (n <= 100) {
    if(n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0){
        console.log(n +" FizzBuzz");
    }else if(n % 5 == 0){
        console.log(n +" Buzz");
    }else if(n % 3 == 0){
        console.log(n +" Fizz");
    }
    n++;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Sugestão faria ele com o for:

```
 for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
     if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0){
         console.log(" FizzBuzz");
     }else if(i % 5 == 0){
         console.log(" Buzz");
     }else if(i % 3 == 0){
         console.log(" Fizz");
     }else {
      console.log(i)   }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui encontrar o problema do meu código! Tudo se tratava de um } no lugar errado! Para deixar documentado, o código funcional fica assim:

```
var n = 1;

while (n <= 100) {
    if ((n % 3) == 0 || (n % 5) == 0) {
        if ((n % 3) == 0 && (n % 5) == 0) {
            console.log("FizzBuzz");
        }
        else if (n % 3 == 0 && (n % 5) !== 0) {
            console.log("Fizz");
        }
        else if ((n % 5) == 0 && (n % 3) !== 0) {
            console.log("Buzz");
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log(n);
    }
n = n + 1;
}
```

Não é a solução mais elegante. Porém, resolve o problema! Abraço a todos!

Comment: Aqui `if ((n % 3) == 0 && (n % 5) == 0)` a comparação `&& (n % 5) == 0` é desnecessária, não precisando verificar se o número é múltiplo de 3 que não seja múltiplo de 5 pois aqui `if ((n % 3) == 0 && (n % 5) == 0)` você já cobriu os casos onde `n` é múltiplo simultâneo de 3 e 5. O mesmo é válido para a linha `if ((n % 5) == 0 && (n % 3) !== 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria dentro de uma função:

```
function fizzBuzz(n) {
   for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
      if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0){
          console.log('FizzBuzz')
      } else if (i % 3 === 0){
          console.log('Fizz')
      } else if ( i % 5 === 0){
          console.log('Buzz')
      } else {
          console.log(i)
      }
  }
}
    
    fizzBuzz(n)
```

// n = 100, por exemplo. É só atribuir o valor de "n" na chamada da função.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).